# Geopandas and Spyder incompability

Tags: input, spyder, geopandas

I want to run modules of Geopandas in Spyder. Apparently Geopandas is compatible with Sypder 4.2.5, (not with any higher version) and I could run code with this combination. However, in one of my code I had to use "input" command and the problem starts there. Sypder 4.2.5 crashes if I try to run input command. From the internet, I came to know that there was a bug in spyder and it was fixed in Spyder 5.3. Now I have no idea how to fix this problem. If I upgrade Spyder, Geopandas will not work. If I don't upgrade spyder, 'input' will not work.

I was trying to run something like the following code

```
def Coditions_R3():
    print("This is R3")
def Coditions_R4():
    print("This is R4")
    
System = input('Please Enter drone system: \n' )
print(System)


if (System == 'R3'):
    Coditions_R3()


    
elif (System == 'R4'):
    Coditions_R4()
```

```
Can anyone help? is there any way around to run geopandas with higher Spyder versions? or use something else in place of input?
```

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) I think Geopandas should work just fine with Spyder 5.3. Where is it stated that the last version that works with it is 4.2.5?

Comment: Because I couldn't be able install spyder 5.0 after I have installed Geopandas. This is the latest version I could install. I would be more than happy if I can install Geopandas with Spyder 5.3. Please let me know how I can do that.

Comment: Ok, if you're using Anaconda, please run these commands in the Anaconda Prompt or a system terminal: `conda create -n spyder-env -c conda-forge spyder geopandas`; `conda activate spyder-env`; `spyder`. The Spyder version that will show up after the last command is the latest one and should let you work with Geopandas without problems.